# linq foreach item in list with more than one matching element

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of cars. Each car has a number of doors. And each door has a color. I want to iterate over the list and select only those cars that have more than one door of a matching color.

I've tried something like this but it's not working like I expect it to:

```
foreach (Car car in cars.Where(c=>c.doors.Select(d=>d.color = "Blue").Count() > 1))
{
     // Do something     
}
```

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace Select with Where and pass a predicate:

```
foreach (Car car in cars.Where(c=>c.doors.Where(d=>d.color == "Blue").Count() > 1))
```

To make it shorter:

```
foreach (Car car in cars.Where(c=>c.doors.Count(d=>d.color == "Blue") > 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `c.color = "blue"` which is assignment.
you should use `c.color == "blue"` or `color.Equals("blue")` for comparison.